# Entity Framework 6.1.0 - Get an error while using Command Interceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interceptor

In my application I do the following

1. Read from database: I Fetch items from database (In parallel, with context per each Task).
2. Write to database: I Create a new Context and for each fetched item, I attach it to that new
   context
3. I defined an Interceptor because I don't want that the EF will save the changes (I need to do it 
   by myself, later, because of performance)
4. **The problem** - after I call SaveChanges() method, the Interceptor being invoked and I have the 
   SQL statement and it's OK. BUT, after the code is executed in the Interceptor side, there is an 
   exception on the Context.SaveChanges() method. Saying that:
   **"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may 
   have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."**

anyone can help me solve this issue ?

thanks.

Hagai

Comment: If you don't want `SaveChanges` to run you either should not call it, or, if it is called automatically by some component, override it in the context and don't do the `base` call. Changing the query will also change the returned number of affected rows.

Comment: I would like SaveChanges to be called since I need **only** the SQL statement generated by EntityFramework... but after I have the SQL in my hand, I would like to cancel (suppress) the EDMX execution.

Comment: Why do you need these SQL statements? If you give some background information (by editing your question) maybe we can help you achieve your goal in some other way.